# Prevent HTTPS to HTTP redirect on nginx AWS?

Tags: nginx, https, amazon-elb

I have a wordpress site with nginx packed into a Docker image behind an AWS ELB Load Balancer. Only HTTPS is enabled on the load balancer.

When I access the URL: `https://example.com/wp-admin/` it works fine but when I access the URL:

`https://example.com/wp-admin` the server fails as it tries to redirect to url: `http://example.com/wp-admin/`

I found this [thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/885046/how-to-prevent-nginx-redirecting-from-https-to-http-on-aws) which has similar issue and applies all three possible solution options suggested but it didn't workout for me.

Here is my nginx config file for the [site](https://pastebin.pl/view/d05dae13)

How do I prevent the HTTPS to HTTP redirect or redirect from HTTPS to HTTPS e.g: `https://example.com/wp-admin` to `https://example.com/wp-admin/`

My [wp-config.php](https://pastebin.pl/view/220746ce)

Comment: I might be missing something but after reading your config files I cannot see where Nginx is handling https at all. Do you have another config including https, it is more likely that is where the issue is because it redirects from https to http.

Comment: Oh wait, I've also just seen the proxy_pass statement. Is Nginx acting as a reverse proxy?

Comment: Yes. And https is being handeled by aws elb.

Comment: You explicitly redirect to `http` with: `rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;` - that statement is not necessary as the `try_files` should perform that function for you anyway.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you very much for pointing it out for me. Sure I'll make the changes.

Comment: I'm not an expert but in my experience if Nginx is the front caching server it should handle https and the backend is http. My setup is Nginx in front with Apache at the back end and the only way to make it work with https was let Nginx do it. Having said that, I know nothing about Amazon services. Was the site originally http? If so, after moving to https it is important to update the wordpress site & home URL under settings too.

Comment: As a side note to my previous comment I also had to add the following to wp-config.php; "if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
    $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];

Comment: In addition, if you must use rewrite statements you can rewrite https:// rather than rewrite $scheme.

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom I'd update my wp-config, checked the wordpress  url settings (it is in https). Still the site breaks without the trailing `/` at the end.

Comment: @PawanRai Perhaps this url might be useful; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645853/add-slash-to-the-end-of-every-url-need-rewrite-rule-for-nginx

Comment: @AdmiralNoisyBottom solved the issue,

Comment: @PawanRai If you resolved it could you add it here as an answer and mark it correct so others can benefit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding:

```
absolute_redirect off;
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

in my  nginx config file for the site solved the issue for me.

Comment: Good to know what sorted it out. You can click the up-arrow to mark it as the accepted & correct answer.